# How do I install Qolibri from source code?

Tags: software-installation, source-code

Qolibri is a EPWING Dictionary/Book Viewer. The official site can be located here: http://qolibri.osdn.jp/

I'm trying to install 'qolibri-1.0.4.src.tar.gz'. Link is here: https://osdn.net/projects/qolibri/releases/29711

[Picture of file's contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9fPn.png)

I tried following the
[instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsUwZ.png):
I installed Qt5 library. I couldn't find 'eblib'. I presume it's a library but I wasn't able to find it. The 'eblib' link does not work. I was given a different link but I don't know what to do with file.

In the terminal I changed directory into the file, I entered 'qmake', 'make'. Finally 'make install': I was given [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxWmv.png)

I looked in the file and the internet and I couldn't find a way to install this, it seems to work fine on Windows but I wouldn't know from first-hand experience. If anyone could please let me know how I can get Qolibri up and running that would be great.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can install EB library [from repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=libeb16-dev):

```
sudo apt-get install libeb16-dev eb-utils eb-doc
```

Then you can compile and install qolibri with the following actions:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential qt4-qmake libqt4-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://acc.dl.osdn.jp/qolibri/29711/qolibri-1.0.4.src.tar.gz
tar -xzf qolibri-1.0.4.src.tar.gz
cd qolibri-1.0.4.src

qmake
make
sudo make install
```

After these steps you can launch `qolibri`.

---

For your information - Ubuntu also has [EBView (*EPWING dictionary viewer*)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=ebview) in the repository, you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install ebview
```

Answer (score -1):

The page mentioned in the "instructions" was closed long thime ago. Only the link below is alive still.
Try this:
EB Library - ftp://ftp.sra.co.jp/pub/misc/eb/eb-4.4.3.tar.bz2

Comment: I downloaded the file. I have no idea what to do with it. You wouldn't happen to have the command? I used 'sudo apt-get install Qt5-default' to install Qt5. How do I install this EB library? Thank you for help!